# Display company currency in dynamics AX SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008, axapta, ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I have to add the company(master) currency to several existing report and i don't get it.

For example for the SSRS report:
"LedgerTrialBalance" (General Ledger/ Transactions/ Summary trial balance)

I only want to display the CurrencyCode in the attached screenshot in a textbox of the above mentioned report.

[With company currency i mean this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoDUG.png)

Have anybody some ideas?

Comment: Could you give more details? E.g. what do you not get, is it an existing or new report, what have you tried so far, ...

Comment: There are several existing reports. I have tried several things, but the problem is, that i am new to dynamics ax and x++. I don't know very much about this. So i search the internet for this issue and the only thing what i found is this: [link](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/87540) and there is no answer since 2009.

Comment: The question in your link seems to be about a Management Reporter report, is that correct, because in your question title it says SSRS report? Could you give us the name of one of the reports and which field in the report should display the company currency (screenshot would be nice)?

Comment: I mean SSRS report. As i said before that was the only thing i've found what going in the same direction. Sure for example the SSRS report "LedgerTrialBalance" (General Ledger/ Transactions/ Summary trial balance). I don't get the second part of your question, which means what field in the report. I need the currency of the screenshot above in several reports in a Textbox on top of the report.

Comment: I see, so for each report you want to add a new field to one of the report data sources, then write some code that fills the new field with the currency and then add the new field to the report design. Have you done any of that so far? Also please include the information from your comments in your question because other people might only read the question and not the comments.

Comment: when this the solution is, then i have to do this. No I haven't done anything so far and i don't know how to implement the points you mentioned now. My knowledge so far applies only to report changes. But not changing a data source or writing some code to fill a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data sources of the `LedgerTrialBalance` report do not contain a field with the company currency code. You would therefore have to modify the report to include such a field. A detailed instruction on how to do that is not a good fit for the Q&A Format of stack overflow, but the high level steps would be:

- identify the data sources of the report
- add a new field to the appropriate data source
- add code to fill the new field with data
- add the new field to the report design

Since you mentioned in the comments that you have only experience with changing report designs I would recommend to get some training in this area and in AX development in general. A particular useful exercise would be to build a complete new report from scratch, this way you could learn about the anatomy of a report.

Comment: thanks for your answers! I have already set up a report but only with fields from the database, i don't know where i have to insert the code to fill the new field in the datasource.

Comment: In case of `LedgerTrialBalance` report, the data provider class `LedgerTrialBalanceDP` is used to populate the report data sources. Take a look at the `populate*` methods of this class to get an idea how this is done.

Comment: I have looked at it, i don't need a new field, just a new parameter. I have already tried to add this parameter in the LedgerTrialBalanceContract class, unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't get the parameter in the report. In classDeclration I added "str accountingCurrency" and further I added a new method "parmAccountCurrency" which looking like that: [
    DataMemberAttribute(identifierStr(accountingCurrency))
]
public Description255 parmAccountCurrency(str _accountingCurrency = accountingCurrency)
{
    accountingCurrency = _accountingCurrency;
    return accountingCurrency;
}

Comment: also in the LedgerTrialBalanceDP in the processReport method I added a attribute (str accountingCurrency) and after contract = this.parmDataContract() as LedgerTrialBalanceContract; I added accountingCurrency = contract.parmAccountCurrency();

Comment: and also in the LedgerTrialBalanceDP in the processReportSummary method i added a attribute (str accountingCurrency)  and after contract = this.parmDataContract() as LedgerTrialBalanceContract; i wrote accountingCurrency = contract.parmAccountCurrency();

Comment: Please create a new question for this.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643221/ax-ssrs-report-parameter-is-shown-but-not-useable-in-the-report)   already done