# AX SSRS Report Parameter is shown but not useable in the report

Tags: ssrs-2008, axapta, ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I want to add a parameter to a SSRS report which uses a report data provider.

I searched the LedgerTrialBalanceContract class in AOT and added in the classDeclaration an attribute "CurrencyCode accountingCurrency;".

After this step, i added a method "parmAccountCurrency" which look like this:

```
[
DataMemberAttribute(identifierStr(accountingCurrency))
]
public CurrencyCode parmAccountCurrency(CurrencyCode _accountingCurrency = accountingCurrency)
{
    //accountingCurrency = _accountingCurrency;
    accountingCurrency = CompanyInfo::standardCurrency();
    return accountingCurrency;
}
```

I know the accountingCurrency will be always the value from "CompanyInfo::standardCurrency();" that's the aim.

In the initialize method from the class LedgerTrialBalanceDP i added additionally the second line from this code snippet:

```
contract = this.parmDataContract() as LedgerTrialBalanceContract;
contract.parmAccountCurrency(CompanyInfo::standardCurrency());
```

After this changes I see my parameter with right value in the AX dialog (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQu5d.png)) but not in VisualStudio.

The aim is to show this parameter on the report in a textbox.

Have anybody an idea what I miss?

Comment: Try refreshing the dataset of the report in Visual Studio.

Comment: yes! Thank you for your help man!

Comment: after adding the textbox with the parameter as contant comes the following exception: "SysOperationDataContractInfo object not initialized.
Stack trace
(C)\Classes\SrsReportDataContractUIBuilder\addDialogField - line 10
(C)\Classes\SysOperationAutomaticUIBuilder\buildGroup - line 41"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "parameter as contant". Did you try an incremental/full cil compile?

Comment: i mean that i wrote in the textbox [@accountingCurrency] to display the parameter on the report. I do not know , because I work on several projects at the same time.. I try it now with full CIL and post my result again.

Comment: Try using the expression `=Parameters!accountingCurrency.Value`. See also [Using Parameters Collection References (Report Builder 3.0 and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255264%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry we had problems with the systems we use. A full CIL compile was the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to refresh the dataset of the report in Visual Studio and do an incremental or full cil compilation after modifying the contract class.